# correct way to update field value in knockout.js

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

my model -

```
public class Model2
        {
            public String Text1;
            public String Text2;
        }
```

action method -

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Model2 model = new Model2();
            model.Text1 = "a";
            return View("Index2", model);
        }
```

html -

```
<input id="text1" type="text" data-bind='value: Text1, keyup: OnText1Change'>
        <input id="text2" type="text" data-bind='value: Text2'>
        <button onclick="PostIndex2Data()">Post Data</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var data = @Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));
        BindIndex2Data();
</script>
```

javascript -

```
function BindIndex2Data() {
    viewModelData = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

   viewModelData.OnText1Change = function () {
    var value = viewModelData.Text1;
    value = value + 1;//or perform some claculation here
    viewModelData.Text2 = ko.observable(value);
    }

    ko.applyBindings(viewModelData);
}
```

All i am trying to do here is get the value from `text1`, perform some calculation on that value and assign that value to `text2`.

Is this the correct way to implement `"ontextchange"` event in knockout?

For some reason my `OnText1Change` event is not getting called here. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Knockout is a two-way binding framework. You do not handle events to change data, you just setup your viewmodel and bindings and trust it to do the work for you. So first you need to remove  `keyup: OnText1Change` and remove function `viewModelData.OnText1Change`.

To change the value of an observable, after you first create it with viewModelData.Text2 = ko.observable(''), you call it like a function:

```
viewModelData.Text2(value);
```

If you want the value of text2 to depend on the value of text 1, you define it like this:

```
viewModelData.Text2 = ko.computed(function(vm) {
    return vm.Text1() + "something";
}, viewModelData);
```

If you want to bind text2, and also have the ability to update it programmatically:

```
viewModelData.Text1.subscribe(function(value) {
    viewModelData.Text2(value + "something");
});
```

Comment: This answer doesn't account for the fact that OP still wants to bind an input element to Text2.

Comment: @Grennis - thanks for your reply. I tried both the suggestions and still the value in Text2 is not getting updated when i enter something in Text1. I tried putting debug points in the function and seems like the function is never getting called. May be you could post a working jsfiddle ?

Comment: can you put what you have in a jsfiddle and I will find the problem.